# General topology I Bourbaki exercise 15 sec. 3 ch. 1

Tags: general-topology, self-learning, problem-solving

The exercise reads as follows (only the first part): *Consider the following subspaces or $\mathbb R$: $X_1=(-1,1)$, $X_2=(-2,1)$ and $X_3=(1,2)$, and let $X$ be the sum of the $X_i$. Let $A_2$ and $A_3$ be the set of irrational numbers contained in $X_2$ and $X_3$ respectively. Let $X/\mathcal R$ be the space obtained by pasting together the $X_i$ along $A_2$ and $A_3$ by means of the homeomorphism $h(x)=x+3$. Show that the subspace $\mu(X_1)$ of $X/\mathcal R$ is not homeomorphic to $X_1$* $\mu:X\rightarrow X/\mathcal R$ is the quotient map).

[image]

To make the exercise 'easier' (or lighter in notation) I think I can translate the spaces since all of them are homemorphic: $X_1=(0,2)$ (to avoid negative numbers), $X_2=(2,5)$ and $X_3=(5,6)$, while the homemorphism $h$ remains unchanged. Then the sum $X$ is just the union of the $X_i$.

Now, the topology on $X/\mathcal R$ is the final topology with respect to the family $\{(X_i,\iota_i\circ \mu)\}_{i=1}^3$. I think $\mu(X_2)$ and $\mu(X_3)$ are not open (neither closed) in $X/\mathcal R$. For example, $\mu^{-1}(\mu(X_2)=X_2\cup Irr(X_3)$; because of the set of irration numbers contained in $X_3$ is not open $\mu(X_2)$ is not open. However, $\mu(X_1)$ should be open in $X\mathcal R$.

Now, the exercise. According to no.5 of section 2, the topology of $X_1$ is strictly finer than the topology induced on $\mu(X_1)$ by $X/\mathcal R$. Then, I should be able to find an open set in $X_1$ which is not open in $\mu(X_1)$. But I can't. For example, if $(a,b)$ is an open interval in $X_1$, then $\mu((a,b))$ is open in $X/\mathcal R$. As a consequence, it is open in $\mu(X_1)$, since it is the intersection of $\mu(X_1)$ with $\mu((a,b))$.  I can't imagine any subset $U\subset\mu(X_1)$ that cannot be write as the intersection of $\mu(X_1)$ and an open subset of $X/\mathcal R$.

EDIT
Regarding Paul Frost's comment, I think that I have to do the following aclaration: In the general description of the book (sec 2 no 5) to each $X_i$ there corresponds a subset $A_i $. But in this exercise there are only two sets indicated: $A_2$ and $A_3$. Then I have set $A_1=\emptyset$. Then, for me the equivalence class of each element of $x\in X_1$ contains only $x$ itself.

EDIT2:

Once @PaulFrost indicated me how the equivalence relation $\mathcal R$ I have been able to elaborate my own answer. I would like you to check it.

The motivation of this exercise is to show that the topology (call it $\tau$) defined on $X_1'=\mu(X_1)$, $\mu$ is the quotient map, by means of $X_1$ and the restriction $\mu|_{X_1}$ which is a bijection, is strictly finer than the topology on $X_1'$ induced by the quotient $X/\mathcal R$ (call it $\tau'$). If I show that I will solved my problem.

Now, I want to prove that there are open sets in $X_1'$ in $\tau$ that are not open in $\tau'$. In particular, I focus on the open intervals of the form $(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)$, with $a<1$ and $\epsilon$ ''very small'' ($0<a-\epsilon<a+\epsilon<1$). Let $I$ be an interval of this type. $I$ is not open in the quotient space because $\mu^{-1}(\mu(I))= I\cup Rat((a+2-\epsilon,a+2+\epsilon))$.

However, it may exist an open set $U\subset X/\mathcal R$ such that $X_1'\cap U=\mu(I)$. Obviously $\mu(I)\subset U$ and hence, $U$ must contain $\mu((a+2-\epsilon,a+2+\epsilon))$ to be open; otherwise $\mu^{-1}(U)\cap X_2$ would not be open. But by the same reason, $U$ must contain also $\mu((a+5-\epsilon,a+5+\epsilon)$. And this forces $U$ to contain $\mu((a+1-\epsilon,a+1+\epsilon))$. Summarizing: an open set in $X/\mathcal R$ which contains $\mu(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)$ must contain the set

$$ \mu\Big((a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)\cup(a+1-\epsilon,a+1+\epsilon)\cup(a+2-\epsilon,a+2+\epsilon)\cup(a+5-\epsilon,a+5+\epsilon) \Big) .$$

But then

$$ X_1'\cap U = \mu\Big((a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)\cup(a+1-\epsilon,a+1+\epsilon)\Big) \neq \mu\Big((a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)\Big). $$

This proves that the searched $U$ does not exists and thus $\mu((a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon))$ is not open in $X_1'$ in $\tau'$.

What do you think? Is my proof valid?

Comment: I believe you do not have the correct interpretation of $Q = X/\mathcal{R}$. The relation $\mathcal{R}$ pastes $X_1$ to the other spaces along $A_2 \cap X_1$. Therefore $\mu$ does not embed $X_1$ into $Y$. This would only be true if your interpretation would be correct.

Comment: @PaulFrost I'm really sure I'm misunderstanding something. But I don't see what you mean. How can $\mathcal R$ past also $X_1$? In the general description given in sec 2 no 5 it is considered one $A_i$ for each $X_i $.  In this case I supposed $A_1$ was the empty set. Do you think the set $A_2$ affects $X_1$ too?

Comment: @PaulFrost I have added an edit to the question, explaining my election for $A_1$.

Comment: If you are right, then $\mu$ maps $X_1$ homeomorphically onto $\mu(X_1)$. But if $\mathcal{R}$ does not affect $X_1$, then the exercise doesn't make much sense. As I already said, I think that the homeomorphism $h(x) = x +3$ (note that the domain is not mentioned!) attaches both $X_1$ and $X_2$ to $X_3$, but of course I cannot sure what Bourbaki's real intention was. However, $h : X_2 \to X_3$ identifies a proper subset of $A_2$ with $A_3$, so why $h : X_1 \to X_3$ shouldn't do the same?

Comment: @PaulsFrost I can do the exercise trying your approach. Anyway, I have added a screenshot with the statement of the exercise.

Comment: Okay. Then both of us have been wrong. $\mathcal{R}$ is generated by the **three** identifications described in (i) - (iii), not only by (i).

Comment: @PaulFrost Really? I thought they were three different exercises inside exercise 15. In fact, I didn't copy those ones in my question. Thanks.

Comment: If you are right, then in exercise (i) $\mu$ maps $X_1$ homeomorphically onto $\mu(X_ 1)$. In (ii) and (iii) this would not be the case.

Comment: @PaulFrost Thanks for your comments and your patience. We hope some other have a definitive answer.

Comment: I would prefer a translation into mathematical English. I dk what "pasting .....together  along .... by means of  the homeomorhism $h$" means.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: To be honest I'm not familiar with this expression and I cannot inagime the shape of the resukting space, neither how it is constructed. However, is not a personal expression but is literally copied from Bourbaki's book. In fact, no 5 of sec 2 is called "Pasting together of topological spaces". Maybe another user with nore expericence than me can give a translation/explanation.

Comment: @PaulFrost: Certainly you were right. You have to consider (i),(ii) and (iii) simultaniously. Following the Bourbaki notation, $A_2$ and $A_3$ gives you the set $A_{23}$, $B_1$ and $B_2$ the set $A_{12}$ and $C_1$ and $C_3$ gives the set $A_{13}$. Thanks again. Please feel free to develop a detailed answer.

Comment: Bourbaki was a French project so the original is likely in French. My comment about translation meant that I suspect the translation may be flawed at that place.

Comment: @Dog_69 I just realized that you have a typo in your question. The correct version is $X_2 = (-2,-1)$. Thus there is no need to translate them $X_i$ to make them disjoint. In fact, $X = X_1 \cup X_2 \cup X_3$ is their sum.

Comment: @PaulFrost Yeah. I didn't realize. They were already disjoint... Anyway,, the idea of the proof should be similar. Is my solution valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You proof is correct. I nevertheless suggest some "streamlining".

First, you should work with the original $X_i$. Next, consider an open $U_1 \subset X_1$ which contains an interval $(a,b)$ with $0 \le a < b \le 1$ and check what it must look like in order that $p(U_1)$ is open in $X'_1$.

So assume that $p(U_1)$ is open in $X'_1$. Then $p(U_1) = U \cap X'_1$ with an open $U \subset Q$. Therefore $p^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$. But $p(C_3 \cap (a+1,b+1)) = p(C_1 \cap (a,b)) \subset p(U_1) \subset U$, thus $C_3 \cap (a+1,b+1) \subset p^{-1}(U)$. This implies $(a+1,b+1)  \subset p^{-1}(U)$. Hence $p(A_2 \cap (a-2,b-2)) = p(A_3\cap (a+1,b+1)) \subset U$ and therefore $A_2 \cap (a-2,b-2)) \subset p^{-1}(U)$. This implies $(a-2,b-2)  \subset p^{-1}(U)$. Hence $p(B_1 \cap (a-1,b-1)) = p(B_2 \cap (a-2,b-2)) \subset U$, thus $B_1 \cap (a-1,b-1) \subset p^{-1}(U)$. This implies $(a-1,b-1) \subset p^{-1}(U)$. But $(a-1,b-1) \subset X_1$ and  $U_1 = p^{-1}(U) \cap X_1$ which implies $(a-1,b-1) \subset U_1$.

This means that $p_1 : X_1 \to X'_1$ is no homeomorphism, since $p((a,b))$ is never open when $(a,b) \subset (0,1)$. However, as I explained, this does not suffice to show that $X_1$ are $X'_1$ are not homeomorphic. To make it more transparent what the problem is, consider the following example.

Let $Y = \bigcup_{n=0}^\infty [2n,2n+1) \subset \mathbb{R}$. Let $\tau$ be the subspace topology inherited from $\mathbb{R}$ and $\tau' = \tau \cup \sigma$, where $\sigma$ is the subspace topology of $[\frac{1}{2},1) \subset \mathbb{R}$. It is easy to see that $\tau'$ is a topology on $Y$ which is strictly finer than $\tau$. However, $(Y,\tau)$ and $(Y,\tau')$ are homeomorphic. In fact, define

$$h : Y \to Y, h(t) =
\begin{cases} 
\frac{t}{2} & t \in [0,1) \\
\frac{t-2}{2} + \frac{1}{2} & t \in [2,3) \\
t-2    & t \in [2n,2n+1), n > 1
\end{cases}$$

$h$ is a bijection and it is readily verifed that $h : (Y,\tau) \to (Y,\tau')$ is a homeomorphism. In fact, $\tau'$ was *defined* so that $\tau' = h(\tau)$.

The proof that $X_1 \not\approx X'_1$ can be done as in my first answer. However, your approach can be used to show that $X'_1$ is not Hausdorff which provides an alternative proof.

Assume $X'_1$ is Hausdorff. Then the points $p(\pm\frac{1}{2})$ can be separated by disjoint open $U'_\pm \subset X'_1$. Since $p_1 : X_1 \to X'_1$ is continuous, the sets $U_\pm = p_1^{-1}(U'_\pm)$ are disjoint open neighborhoods of $\pm\frac{1}{2}$ in $X_1$. Choose a subinterval $(a,b) \subset (0,1)$ such that $\frac{1}{2} \in (a,b) \subset U_+$. Since $p(U_+) = U'_+$ is open in $X'_1$, we know that $-\frac{1}{2} \in (a-1,b-1) \subset U_+$. But this means $U_+ \cap U_- \ne \emptyset$ which is  a contradiction.

Not that this argument can be generalized to show that $p(x_1), p(x_2)$ have disjoint open neighborhods in $X'_1$ if and only if $\lvert x_1 - x_2 \rvert \ne 1$.

Comment: Thanks again for your useful answers and your patience. I have to say that this exercise is at the beginning of the chapter, before Haussdorff or compact spaces. Then probably Bourbaki was looking for another proof. Anyway, it is enough for me. Thank you very much (PD: this answer should score more than 25).

Comment: @Dog_69 Let us do without using the word "Hausdorff". We found two points in $X'_1$ which do not have disjoint open neighborhoods. If we would have $X_1 \approx X'_1$, then there must also exist two points in $X_1$ which do not have disjoint open neighborhoods. But this is not true.

Comment: Yes. Fantastic. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The three "pastings" give us three relations $\sim_\nu$ on the sum $X = X_1 \cup  X_2 \cup X_3$. Explictly we have

$a_2 \sim_{(i)}(a_2) h_{(i)}(a_2) = a_2 + 3$ for $a_2\in A_2$

$b_1 \sim_{(ii)} h_{(ii)}(b_1) = b_1 - 1$ for $b_1 \in B_1$

$c_1 \sim_{(iii)} h_{(iii)}(c_1) = c_1 + 1$ for $c_1 \in C_1$

Let $\mathcal{R}$ denote the equivalence relation on $X$ generated by these $\sim_\nu$ and let $p : X \to X/\mathcal{R} = Q$ denote the quotient map. It is obviuos that $p$ does not identify distinct points *within* any $X_i$ because the $h_\nu$ are injective. Hence $p$ establishes a bijection between $X_i$ and $X'_i = p(X_i) \subset Q$, but clearly $X'_1 \cap X'_2 = p(B_1) = p(B_2) = B \ne \emptyset$, $X'_1 \cap X'_3 = p(C_1) = p(C_3) = C \ne \emptyset$ and $X'_2 \cap X'_3 = p(A_2) = p(A_3) = A \ne \emptyset$. It is easy to see that $X'_1 \cap A = \emptyset$. Moreover
$$Q = p(X_1) \cup p(X_2) \cup p(X_3) = p(X_1) \cup p(X_2 \setminus B_2) \cup p(X_3\setminus C_3) = $$ 
$$p(X_1) \cup p(A_2) \cup p(A_3) = X'_1 \cup A .$$

Let us see how the topology on  $Q = X'_1 \cup A$ looks like. Write $U \subset Q$ as $U = U'_1 \cup U'$ with $U'_1 \subset X_1, U' \subset A$. There exist unique $U_1 \subset X_1, U_2 \subset A_2$ such that $p(U_1) = U'_1, p(U_2) = U'$. We have
$$p^{-1}(U) = p^{-1}(p(U_1)) \cup p^{-1}(p(U_2)) = U_1 \cup h_{(ii)}(U_1 \cap B_1)\cup h_{(iii)}(U_1 \cap C_1) \cup U_2 \cup h_{(iii)}(U_2) .$$
Now $U$ is open in $Q$ if and only if $p^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$. The latter means that

1) $U_1$ is open in $X_1$

2) $V_ 2 = h_{(ii)}(U_1 \cap B_1) \cup U_2$ is open in $X_2$

3) $V_3 = h_{(iii)}(U_1 \cap C_1) \cup h_{(i)}(U_2)$ is open in $X_3$.

Assume that $U_1 \subset (0,1)$. Then $U_1 \cap B_1 = \emptyset$ and we get $V_2 = U_2 \subset A_2$ which possible only when $U_2 = \emptyset$. Thus $V_3 = h_{(iii)}(U_1 \cap C_1)$ which is possible only when $U_1 = \emptyset$. This shows that $p_1 : X_1 \stackrel{p}{\rightarrow} X'_1$ is no homeomorphism.

Now let us assume that there exists a homeomorphism $h : X'_1 \to X_1$. Then $h' = h \circ p_1 :  X_1 \to X_1$ is a continuous bijection. This is possible only if $h'$ is strictly increasing or strictly decreasing. W.l.o.g. assume it is strictly increasing. Then $\lim_{t \to -1} h'(t) = -1$ and  $\lim_{t \to 1} h'(t) = 1$. This shows that $h'$ has a continuous extension $H : [-1,1] \to [-1,1]$ such $H(\pm1) = \pm1$. Therefore $H$ is a continuous bijection between compact spaces and thus a homeomorphism. We conclude that $h'$ is also one. This implies that $p_1 = h^{-1} \circ h'$ is a homeomorhism which is not true.

Therefore $X_1$ and $X'_1$ are not homeomorphic.

Comment: Very technical proof. I wrote my solution just noticing that the image under $p$ of some open intervals onf$X_1$ go by pairs. For example the image under the quotient map of an open interval $I=(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)\subset X_1$ with $a<1$ is not open in $Q$ and that to get an open set $U\subset Q$ such that $X_1'\cap U=p(I)$ the set $U$ must contain (ignorng other sets) the image under $p$ of the interval $(a+1-\epsilon,a+1+\epsilon)$, which is also contained in $X_1'$. In my opinion this shows that the subspace topology on $X_1$ is coarser that the final with respecto to $(X_1,p_1)$.

Comment: @Dog_69 Then you should write an official answer to your own question. However, note that if a specific continuous bijection between two spaces is no homeomorphism, this does not mean that there exists no homeomorphism.

Comment: Yes, that $p$ is not s homemorphism does not mean that there isn't any homeomorphism. However, my proof should be enough to show what I said, that I the subspace topology on $X_1'$ is coarser than the final. And because $X_1'$ with the second topology is homeomorphic to $X_1$ then they are not homemorphic. Is this proof valid?

Comment: @Dog_69 $p_1 : X_1 \to X'_1$ is a continuous bijection. $X_1$ has the standard topology as an open real interval. $X'_1$ has the subspace topology inherited from $Q$, where $Q$ has the quotient topology (= final topology) induced by $p : X \to Q$. Even if we know that there exist open $U \subset X_1$ such that  $p_1(U)$ is not open in $X'_1$, it can only be interpreted in the sense that we have two topologies on the same set $X_1$, one of them strictly coarser than the other. But this does not exclude that there exists a bijection $\phi : X_1 \to X_1$ mixing the points in a non-trivial way

Comment: such that $\phi(U)$ is open if and and only if $U$ is. The last step in my proof used the fact that $X_1$ is an *interval* to prove that no such $\phi$ can exist. But I encourage you again to write your own answer.

Comment: I'm not going to write an answer with my solution because I'm not sure about it. However, I have edited my answer to include it (EDIT2). Now my question should be: _Is my solution valid?_

Comment: I couldn't include your citation before @PaulFrost